# NSMenuItem key equivalent isn't setting

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have set menu item key equivalent to cmd- . But when I am running the application its not there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's because another key binding uses that same key equivalent

Comment: When I am running other applications (not developed by me) its working correct.

Comment: I have the same issue. The key equivalent doesn't really seems to be in use, since I get a BEEP when I press it..